# how to create android SQLite database for many languages like string values

Tags: android, sqlite

Is there a capability in Android to create SQLite database files for English and other languages and behave just like string values? All I have to do is to  deal with one code and the Android pick the suitable database according to device language.

Comment: You can create as many databases as you need. Just give them all different names.

Comment: Or you can create a single database with multiple tables. Or you can create a database with a table with a field which indicates the language.

Comment: Thank you for your comment .but I want it  just like string I create many databases with name shop but it will differ in language shop-fr,shop-ar...etc and the android pick the one of them automatically as it picks string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `values` localized resources directories to do that:

```
/res
|
----/values
|   |
|   ---- strings.xml  <-- contains your default language values (english for example)
|
----/values-de
|   |
|   ---- strings.xml  <-- contains your german languages values
|
----/values-fr
|   |
|   ---- strings.xml  <-- contains your french languages values
|
(etc)
```

In each of these localized files, define the language-specific parameters of your data access code. In this example, this is the database's file name:

- default `strings.xml` file:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <resources>
       <string name="db_name">myDatabase_EN</string>
  ...
  </resources>
  ```
- "-de" `strings.xml` file:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <resources>
       <string name="db_name">myDatabase_DE</string>
       ...
  </resources>
  ```
- "-fr" `strings.xml` file:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <resources>
       <string name="db_name">myDatabase_FR</string>
       ...
  </resources>
  ```

And so on for each language your app handles.

Then, the database file choice becomes transparent for your code thanks to the use of [`Context.getString(int resId)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString(int)). This method selects automatically the resource `String`s that correspond to the user's device `Locale`. Should no localized `String` match `getString()` picks the default one:

```
private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper  {

    ...

    private DatabaseHelper(Context ctx) {
        super(ctx, ctx.getString(R.string.db_name), null, dbVersion); 
        // R.string.db_name corresponds to the localized String 
        // resource "db_name", based on the users's device Locale.
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        ... 
    } 

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        ...
    }

    ...

}
```

In this example a different database is opened depending on the language. But the same way, you could decide to access to differents tables of a unique database, or to select differents fields from the various tables of your database.

Comment: Very smart idea, do you know if is there some similar aproximation using ROOM? https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room

Comment: @jms Thank you! But I don't know what ROOM is actually. So I have no idea, sorry :)

Comment: this will be a problem if user switches his language.. he will not get his saved data in other language in new language

Comment: @SiddarthG This is not the question that the OP asked.